# Google Sheets formula - Named ranges for dates

Tags: google-sheets

In excel, I would have used the following for a named date range:

"date" =Y$11
"next_date" = Z$11

the formula I want to use is:
=(Weekday(date,2)>Weekday(next_date,2))*1

Expected output: Mon-Thur would be 0 and Fri would be 1

This works in Excel.  However, I do not have Excel available to me and am using Google Sheets.

I have tried many permutations to no avail.  Roadblocks thus far in Google Sheets:

1. In named ranges, cannot use $

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share an example of the data that you have and the expected output? Maybe this is not possible with Google Sheets' named ranges but there might be a different approach.

Comment: I have a timeline (building a ganntt chart) and was hoping for the following logical test:
1) Weekday of "date" is greater than Weekday of "next_date"
2) The expression should return a TRUE result
3) If multiplied by 1, all the cells that are Friday would = 1 and all other days would be 0